# Why cannot connect to SQL Server by the full server name with instance name?

Tags: sql-server, connection

For some reasons, I cannot connect to my SQL Server with full name + instance name (e.g. server_name\MSSQLSERVER) by SMSS. However, I can connect by simply using just server_name or localhost.

When I check SQL server configuration manager, I did see my sqlserver is running with "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER).

Comment: In configuration manager, have you enabled named pipes?

Answer (score 1):

The default instance *servicename* is MSSQLSERVER, but the instance name is empty (just the servername).

This *may* occur (rarely) when you are not using the SQL Browser Service **and** are running on a non-standard port; in that case, the instance name alone is not sufficient to reach the instance.

A non-default instance has the Windows service MSSQL$INSTANCENAME; the default is (oddly) MSSQLSERVER (no $).

Comment: Correct, the instance you have installed is the default instance so you will connect using only the server name.  If you want to connect with server\instance then install another instance of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your running a default instance, you dont need to connect using *hostname\instancename*, *hostname* is enough

Answer (score 0):

Instances have to be enabled to make this work (during setup, not sure if its possible to enable this afterwards).
If instances are not enabled, the only availiable (single) instance will be the default.

Also see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265808 for more information about connecting to instances.

Edit: see also the comment by Thor Erik, you can enable named pipes afterwards it seems :)